# selective replacement rules in mathematical expression

Tags: replacement, symbolic

I am trying to write a replacement rule that will substitute values for d_1 and d_2 only the places they are outside the Phi equation:

[image]

I was able to write a function that replaced Phi[d_1] and Phi[d_2] with Phi[d1] and Phi[d2], thereby creating two new variables and then apply my transformation rules only to the original d_1 and d_2. But this does not generalize for when the function Phi contains a linear combination of d_1 and d_2, or some other value that I don't want to substitute for. Can you help me figure how to do this?

In mathematica code:

```
E^(-2 r T) k^2 (1 + E^(
  2 Subscript[d, 1] (Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2])) + 
  2 E^(1/2 (\!\(
  \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(d\), \(1\), \(2\)] - 
  \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(d\), \(2\), \(2\)]\))) (-1 + \[CapitalPhi][
   Subscript[d, 1]]) - 
  1] (Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2])) \[CapitalPhi][
  2 Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2]] - \[CapitalPhi][Subscript[d,
  2]])
```

Or, for easier copy/paste (brackets corrected):

```
E^(-2 r T) k^2 (1 + E^(2 Subscript[d, 1] (Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2])) + 2 E^(1/2 (\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(d\), \(1\), \(2\)] -\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(d\), \(2\), \(2\)]\))) (-1 + \[CapitalPhi][Subscript[d, 1]]) - E^(2 Subscript[d, 1] (Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2])) \[CapitalPhi][2 Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2]] - \[CapitalPhi][Subscript[d,2]])
```

Comment: Please enter your expression in a code block using Mathematica code.

Comment: edited accordingly

Comment: There brackets don't balance so the expression will not evaluate

Comment: Something on the lines of `yourexpression /. {a : Φ[___] :> a, 
  Subscript[d, a : 1 | 2] :> ToExpression["d" <> IntegerString[a]]}`? The first replacement prevents other replacements of expressions with head `Φ`.

Comment: corrected the brackets on the copy/paste version

Comment: The copy/paste version is actually harder to copy and paste because there is a scroll... (the other version is in fact easier to copy/paste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could exploit the fact that `ReplaceAll` does not replace the same thing twice.

For instance:

```
In[505]:= eq /. {a_Φ :> a, 
   Subscript[d, a : 1 | 2] :> 
    ToExpression["d" <> IntegerString[a]]}

Out[505]//InputForm=
(k^2*(1 + E^(2*d1*(d1 - d2)) + 2*E^((d1^2 - d2^2)/2)*
    (-1 + Φ[Subscript[d, 1]]) - E^(2*d1*(d1 - d2))*
    Φ[2*Subscript[d, 1] - Subscript[d, 2]] - Φ[Subscript[d, 2]]))/
 E^(2*r*T)
```

(`eq` is the equation in your question)

The first replacement `a_Φ :> a` doesn't do anything, but it tells `ReplaceAll` not to replace sub-expressions of `Φ` anymore.

P.S. Thanks @march for the comment (`a : Φ[___]` changed to `a_Φ`).

Comment: In this case, you could also do `a_Φ :> a`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for the prompt reply, this was exactly what i was looking for.