# How to ReplaceAll except within specified heads

Tags: replacement

`ReplaceAll[expr, rule]` and `ReplaceRepeated[expr, rule]` search through all subexpressions of `expr` applying `rule` where they match.

Are there built-in *Mathematica* functions that do the same thing, except not make any replacements inside specified `Head`s (that is, it shouldn't look at any subexpressions within specified `Head`)?

I'd imagine something like `ReplaceAllRestricted[expr, rule, heads]` and `ReplaceRepeatedRestricted[expr, rule, heads]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(125746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125746)

Comment: @JHM actually, I'd close the other one in favor of this one, as it is more general.

Comment: A possibility is to use [``Developer`ReplaceAllUnheld``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/ReplaceAllUnheld.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could exploit the fact that `Replace` and its derivatives do not match the same pattern twice in one iteration. Thus:

```
ReplaceAllRestricted[expr_, rules_List, heads_List] :=
 expr /. Join[a : Blank[#] :> a & /@ heads, rules];

ReplaceAllRestricted[{a[1], b[1], c[1]}, {1 -> 3}, {c}]
```

> `{a[3], b[3], c[1]}`

and

```
ReplaceRepeatedRestricted[expr_, rules_List, heads_List] := 
 expr //. Join[a : Blank[#] :> a & /@ heads, rules];

ReplaceRepeatedRestricted[{a[a[a[1]]], b[b[b[1]]]}, {_[1] -> 1}, {b}]
```

> `{1, b[b[b[1]]]}`

`a : Blank[#] :> a & /@ heads` adds non-functional replacement rules that replaces a pattern with some head with itself.

However, when you run the code, because *Mathematica* 'replaced' the pattern (with the pattern itself), it does not further replace the sub-expressions.

Comment: I really like this.  If you don't mind, I have added "`_List`" to the final two arguments in the LHS of your definitions to suggest usage.  Feel free to roll back.