# Replace at given levels, but ignore subexpressions with specified heads

Tags: replacement

I'm implementing a function `tacit1` that constructs a pure function by applying all `Symbol`s to `#`. E.g.

```
tacit1[IntegerPartitions[Max, Length/2, Select[Most, # < 10&]]]

(* IntegerPartitions[Max[#], Length[#]/2, Select[Most[#], # < 10&]]& *)
```

However, I also need the ability to escape symbols, say with a head `tacitVerbatim`, so that `tacit1` does not enter expressions with head `tacitVerbatim`. (Maybe `Compose` and other higher-order functions should automatically be excluded too.)

```
tacit1[SortBy[Most, tacitVerbatim[ Abs @* Sin]]]
(* SortBy[Most[#], Abs @* Sin]& *)
```

I tried the answer to [How to ReplaceAll except within specified heads](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125918/61597), but `ReplaceAll` enters Heads by default, and tries to replace the `IntegerPartitions` head with `IntegerPartitions[#]`. I also need to specify levels to keep the outer `Function` from being replaced.

`Replace` examines expressions from deepest to shallowest, so the trick that keeps `ReplaceAll` out of certain expressions doesn't work.

I'm thinking of manually searching the expression tree, but is there a more elegant idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
SetAttributes[{tacit1, hide}, HoldAll]
tacit1[e_]:=With[{g = hide[e]},
    Replace[
        g[[1]],
        s_Symbol /; !MemberQ[Attributes[s], Temporary] :> s[#],
        {2, Infinity}
    ] /. g[[2]]
]

hide[e_] := Reap[
    ReplaceAll[
        Function[e],
        tacitVerbatim[t_] :> RuleCondition @ Module[{x}, Sow[x, Unevaluated[t]]]
    ],
    _,
    toRuleDelayed
]

SetAttributes[toRuleDelayed,HoldAll]

toRuleDelayed[x_, {s_}] := s :> x
```

Your examples:

```
tacit1[IntegerPartitions[Max, Length/2, Select[Most,#<10&]]]
```

> IntegerPartitions[Max[#1], Length[#1]/2, Select[Most[#1], #1 < 10 &]] &

```
tacit1[SortBy[Most, tacitVerbatim[ Abs @* Sin]]]
```

> SortBy[Most[#1], Abs@*Sin] &